# Deserialize several elements in an array from string to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, local-storage, material-table

I am in dire need of help. I need to make it possible for the user to store into his localStorage an array of 25 elements with each of them having nested elements themselves. The cell style and the element "render" includes JSX-Elements like this:

```
 render: row => (
    <div>
      <Dialog text={row.Bemerkungen} />
    </div>
  ),
```

I can store the array by stringifying it, but when retrieving it, I have issues deserialize the function-strings, see in the image below:

[image]

Would appriciate any help!

Comment: I know you can eval a string but i'm not positive that's what you're looking for. If you 
`let funcString = "const test = () => {console.log(2)};\r\ntest()";
eval(funcString);` it will execute that string

Comment: You can also use `new Function(/* function code as string */)`